# In socket.io, compression perMessageDeflate not working

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I see the headers present in both the request and the response

```
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate
```

and yet, the data sent over the socket is still the same( verified for large and small size data).

Please clarify the following for me:

1. Data sent in the frames of the socket should be compressed right?
2. Will i be able to see the compressed data on the developer tools of chrome under the frames tab of the socket ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, unless the original message size is below 1024 bytes (which is the default threshold that [`engine.io`](https://github.com/socketio/engine.io#methods-1) uses to determine if a message should be compressed or not).
2. It doesn't look like it (it's a protocol option so I think that Chrome will perform the decompression transparently, just like compressed HTTP responses).

Comment: Is there any way i can confirm this compression happening? I need this compression on the data, as i am working on a lower bandwidth.

Comment: I haven't found a way to confirm it, other than adding some logging statements in the `ws` module to see if it performs the compression :(

Comment: tried by logging and measuring the time for the frame to transmit. didnt find any diff with 200KB of data. Chrome by default is not sending any value for client_max_window_bits. and my server is rejecting this request and not sending it in the response. How do I set this value?

Comment: Hmm try this: `let client = io(..., { transportOptions : { websocket : { clientMaxWindowBits : ... } } })`

Comment: I might be wrong, it's `socket.io` passing options to `engine.io` passing options to `ws` so it's a bit messy :)

Comment: @Learner You can use a Network Packet Capture like Wireshark and check the TCP data streams. If you use a **not** Secure Websocket protocol (wss) you should be able to see the socket.io messages in plain text like HTTP data. Never tried with Websocket protocol packets but it should work. If you can't see a "readable plain text" data it means that it's compressed. Or atleast HTTP protocol act like that. Hope it helps.